# How to Get UTC of file DateLastModified in VBA?

Tags: vba, file, ms-access, utc, dst

I need to find from an Access DB if any file in a folder got changed. For this reason I created a table containing the file information (name and DateLastModified). However there is the problem, that Windows always adjusts the DateLastModified to the local time zone and this value will even change on daylight savings (means: DateLastModified will change when DST activates/deactivates)!

To overcome this and to find the files true 'DateLastModified'-date I use FileSystemObject to get 'DateLastModified' and convert the returned value to UTC by means of Function GetUTC. Then I store this value in the database. I carefully tested GetUTC - it will return a value not depending on DST (tested for time zones CET and CEST).

Re-querying the folder and comparing a newly calculated 'DateLastModified' against the stored 'DateLastModified' will fail for approximately 15%-35% of the files - is seems random which files fail! Could it be that DT.GetVarDate(False) in GetUTC does not always return the same binary value?

However using debug.print always shows the *same Date & Time* for the failing files and the value stored in the database! MS specs says the resolution of datatype 'Date' is one second. So I do not understand how 2 Dates that show the same value will result to false when compared! Sample output of a failed file:

```
1477   493   18.12.2013 19:03:26   18.12.2013 19:03:26   scanColor0010.pdf
```

How can I make this work?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public ws As Workspace
Public db As Database

Function GetUTC(dLocalTimeDate As Date) As Date
Dim DT As Object
Dim curTime As Date
  curTime = Now()
  Set DT = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
  DT.SetVarDate curTime
  GetUTC = dLocalTimeDate - curTime + DT.GetVarDate(False)
End Function



'------------------------------------------------------------
' Test_UTC_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Test_UTC_Click()
Dim colFiles As New Collection
Dim vFile As Variant
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim f As File
Dim lngCountWrong As Long
Dim lngCount As Long

  Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
  Set db = CurrentDb()

  RecursiveDir colFiles, "Y:\", "*.pdf", False
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  For Each vFile In colFiles
    Set f = fso.GetFile(vFile)
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblFiles.*, tblFiles.fileName FROM tblFiles WHERE (((tblFiles.fileName)=""" & f.Name & """));")
    rst.MoveFirst
    lngCount = lngCount + 1
    If (rst!fileDateModified = GetUTC(f.DateLastModified)) Then
      'Ok, this is always expected
    Else
      'Uuuups - what went wrong?
      lngCountWrong = lngCountWrong + 1
      Debug.Print lngCount, lngCountWrong, rst!fileDateModified, GetUTC(f.DateLastModified), f.Name
    End If
    rst.Close
    Set f = Nothing
    DoEvents
  Next vFile
  Debug.Print "finished", lngCount
  Set fso = Nothing
End Sub


'------------------------------------------------------------
' CreateTestdata_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub CreateTestdata_Click()
Dim colFiles As New Collection
Dim vFile As Variant
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim f As File

  Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
  Set db = CurrentDb()
  
  db.Execute "DELETE tblFiles.* FROM tblFiles;"
  Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblFiles.* FROM tblFiles;")
  
  RecursiveDir colFiles, "Y:\", "*.pdf", False
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  For Each vFile In colFiles
    Set f = fso.GetFile(vFile)
    rst.AddNew
    rst!filename = f.Name
    Debug.Print f.Name
    rst!fileDateModified = GetUTC(f.DateLastModified)
    rst.Update
    Set f = Nothing
    DoEvents
  Next vFile
  Set fso = Nothing
  rst.Close
  Debug.Print "Finished creating"
  MsgBox "Finished creating"
End Sub
```

Comment: Possibly a floating point issue.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite

```
   If (rst!fileDateModified = GetUTC(f.DateLastModified)) Then
      'Ok, this is always expected
    Else
```

to

```
   If Datediff("s",rst!fileDateModified,GetUTC(f.DateLastModified)) = 0 Then
      'Ok, this is always expected
    Else
```

Further reading on [Datediff](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/functions/datediff-function.htm)

Further reading on [How to store, calculate, and compare Date/Time data in Microsoft Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/store-calculate-compare-datetime-data). Although this article is on Access it should be similar in Excel

Comment: I applied this patch. It greatly improved behavior! However there is one (1) file left, that shows now a 1 second time difference for every call! I looped the code for this file and this 1 second difference existed for each of 50'000 calls! Any explanation for this? -- And thank you for the links!

Comment: After investing some more time into this problem I think the problem occurring now is due to the fact, that GetUTC does arithmetic with dates as well:
GetUTC = dLocalTimeDate - curTime + DT.GetVarDate(False)
I tried solving this with DateAdd / DateDiff as well, but ran into Typ-conversion problems. As a workaround I decided to use

   If Abs(DateDiff("s",rst!fileDateModified,GetUTC(f.DateLastModified))) <= 2 Then
      'Ok, this is always expected
    Else

I'm not yet persuaded that this will work under all circumstances!

Comment: Then it might be better to use `Abs(rst!fileDateModified -GetUTC(f.DateLastModified)) <= 10E-4`.

Comment: Thank you. No. As 'GetUTC' returns sometimes a second difference the threshold needs to be at least 1 second. Further there used to be 2 second problem in the past when copying files between FAT, FAT32 and NTFS. It's rather unlikely that someone modifies a file and saves it back within 2 seconds (well at least for the files (.PDF receipts) concerned here - might be different for machine generated Logs...).